# Changing the current filename to a different one using fopen

Tags: c, file, io

I'm currently practicing File I/O in C. I created a program where I get a file and extract data from it and I would like an option to change the file that is being read. The problem that I'm encountering is that for example I have two files: `sample1.txt` and `sample2.txt`. If I chose `sample1.txt` as the first file to be read and then I wanted to change the file to `sample2.txt` what ends up happening is that the filename does not change to `sample2.txt` but instead always stays what ever filename the first file has.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
 char file_location[100]={0};
 char new_location[100]={0};
  FILE* fPointer=NULL;
  int choice;

  printf("Enter the filename that you wish to open.\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",file_location);               // I enter sample1.txt//
  printf("%s\n",file_location);
  fPointer=fopen(file_location,"r"); // success,sample1.txt is currently being read.//

if (fPointer==NULL)
        {
            printf("File error!,invalid file name! program will now exit.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
else
        {
            printf("Success!\n");       
        }
    printf("Do you want to change the file being read\n); //Now I want to change the file,from sample1.txt to sample2.txt//
    prinft("Enter 1 to change, 0 to exit the program\n); 
    do{
      scanf("%d",&choice);                     
      printf("You entered %d\n",choice);
      if(choice<0||choice>1)
        {
         printf("Error,please choose between 1 and 0\n");
         }

  }while(choice!=1||choice!=0);
      switch(choice)                   // I enter 1,go to case1//
    {
        case 0:
        printf("Exiting program now\n");
        exit(0);
        break;
        case 1:
        fclose(fPointer);
        printf("Enter the filename that you wish to open.\n");    
        scanf("%[^\n]s",new_location);          //scanf does not even prompt me to enter a string.//
        printf("%s\n",new_location);     //nothing prints//
        fPointer=fopen(new_location,"r"); // fpointer still points to sample1.txt//
        break;
    }   

return 0;           
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why my code keeps failing?
Any constructive criticism ,notes about File I/O  is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a `break` statment after the `case 1` and the default one

Comment: @JoaoTorres Thank you, edited  the code.

Comment: @Noobplox23 **indent** your code!

Comment: How do you expect scanf to prompt you? What does the format string `"%[^\n]s"` do, exactly? Why do you read `new_location` and then proceed to use something else?

Comment: @n.m. Hi thank you , I replaced it with `new_location` but the problem still persists.

Comment: @xing Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that your code mishandles newlines. This method of obtaining input probably does not do what you think it does:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",new_location);
```

First, there is no reason for the trailing `s` here. Second, this will leave a trailing newline behind in the input stream. This newline is ignored when you call `scanf("%d",&choice);`, since the `%d` conversion specifier skips over leading whitespace characters. But, this second call to `scanf()` also leaves a newline character behind, and this is not ignored by the final call to `scanf()`, since `%[^\n]` tells `scanf()` to read characters until a newline is encountered.

One fix is to simply remove the scanset from your `scanf()` statements:

```
scanf("%s", new_location);
```

This will ignore leading whitespace characters, so the newline left behind from the previous call to `scanf()` will be ignored.

Also, when you open the new file, you are using `file_location` instead of `new_location`.

You will need to change your `do` loop condition to:

```
while(choice != 1 && choice != 0);
```

since you want to repeat the loop only if the user enters a number that is both not 0 and not 1.

If you want to read lines that include spaces, which is what `[^\n]` is sometimes used for, a better alternative is to use `fgets()`. This function keeps the newline, so you will need to remove it from the filenames. Also, if you are using `fgets()` to get the strings, it is best to use `fgets()` to get the numeric input, by reading the user input into a buffer and using `sscanf()` to parse it. Then your input code would look like:

```
/* Get first filename, and remove the newline */
printf("Enter the filename that you wish to open.\n");
fgets(file_location, sizeof file_location, stdin);
file_location[strcspn(file_location, "\r\n")] = '\0';  // remove newline

...

/* Get numeric input; this keeps the newline, so it does not interfere
 * with the next call to `fgets()` */
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &choice);

...

/* Get the new filename, and remove the newline */
printf("Enter the filename that you wish to open.\n");
fgets(new_location, sizeof new_location, stdin);
new_location[strcspn(new_location, "\r\n")] = '\0';  // remove newline
```

Comment: Thank you !  I will try your suggestion!

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Thank you! I just started learning C this semester and File I/O was the last  topic so I wanted to practice File I/O before my finals.

Comment: @Noobplox23-- I have added some comments about using `fgets()` for this, which is a better solution. This allows the entry of strings containing spaces, which is the usual use for the `[^\n]` specifier, but is easier to work with, and more flexible. If you want to read about removing trailing newlines from strings, [this is a good link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).